# MathLink and writing *.tm files

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

My goal is to use MathLink to access the functions in [sofa](http://www.iausofa.org/current_C.html) (Standards of Fundamental Astronomy)

So far I have had mixed success. I have very little C programing experience so I am hoping to get access to these algorithms via MathLink.

I have a very simple C code file that loads the sofa libraries:

```c
#include "mathlink.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sofa.h"
#include "sofam.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
return MLMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Then, from the sofa documentation I find function definitions like:

```c
double iauAnp(double a)
```

Which I then turn into inputs, in the sofa.tm file

```
:Begin:
:Function:       iauAnp
:Pattern:        iauAnp[i_Real]
:Arguments:      { i }
:ArgumentTypes:  { Real64 }
:ReturnType:     Real64
:End:

:Evaluate: iauAnp::usage = "iauAnp[x] Normalize angle into the range 0 <= a < 2pi."
```

I'm then able to compile this and load it into *Mathematica* via the `Install[]` function. So I know I can turn the crank once for a simple case.

The question:
How do I write the lines for the sofa.tm file for the following function?

```c
void iauC2i00a(double date1, double date2, double rc2i[3][3])
```

My understanding of the workings of this function is that `date1` and `date2` are inputs and the 2D array, `rc2i` is returned by reference.

I would like the *Mathematica* function to look like this:

```
rc2i = iauC2i00a[date1, date2]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Caution:** All code below is untested written from the top of my head. It should only serve as help for the explanation and is most likely not compilable.

In your last case you need to do what is usually done with all library-calls: you write a wrapper function. This is basically a function which takes the input, prepares everything (if there is something), calls your library function, collects the result and sends everything back to *Mathematica*.

Your logic should work as follows. You define a template which calls your wrapper function. What you want is to send two `double` values in and get one `double` array out.

```
:Begin:
:Function:       MLiauC2i00a
:Pattern:        MLiauC2i00a[date1_?NumericQ, date2_?NumericQ]
:Arguments:      {N[date1], N[date2]}
:ArgumentTypes:  { Real64, Real64 }
:ReturnType:     Manual
:End:
```

Note that I have put `Manual` as return type which says: I will do the work of putting the result back to *Mathematica* by myself using *MathLink* functions.

```
void MLiauC2i00a(double date1, double date2) {
  double rc2i[3][3];
  iauC2i00a(date1, date2, rc2i);

  MLPutFunction(stdlink, "List", 3);
    MLPutReal64List(stdlink, rc2i[0], 3);
    MLPutReal64List(stdlink, rc2i[1], 3);
    MLPutReal64List(stdlink, rc2i[2], 3);
  return;
}
```

In the first part I define `rc2i` and call the library-function. Afterwards the result is stored in `rc2i`. To send it back to *Mathematica*, I build up the expression exactly as you would do it in *Mathematica* itself:

```
List[rc2i[0],rc2i[1],rc2i[2]]
(* {rc2i[0],rc2i[1],rc2i[2]} *)
```

where the `rc2i` are then again lists of length 3 of real numbers. Now you can probably guess that the last argument to [`MLPutFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/c/MLPutFunction.html) is the number of list-elements we want to supply.

Needless to say, that you could call the `MLPutReal64List` functions in a loop if you have more than 3.

Comment: Thank you this works! (Except in the :Pattern: the second `data` should be a `data2`) I tried to edit it but an edit must be at least 6 letters.

Comment: @c186282 I changed it. Nice that it helped you.